# Gmail API unable to get entire message contents

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to read the email using Gmail API using RAW and FULL format. For some emails it don't return the full email contents in both formats. It contains only header part and not body contents. The source email have data in email body but Gmail api fails to read it. When I try to store the same email locally, it gives error as 'Invalid MIME Contents'

Here is my sample code

```
     Email Emailobj              = null;                     
 UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest MessageGetRequestObj = null;
 MessageGetRequestObj            = GmailServiceObj.Users.Messages.Get(UserEmailID, ItemID);
 MessageGetRequestObj.Format     = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
 MessageGetRequestObj.Fields     = "id,threadId,labelIds,internalDate,sizeEstimate,raw,payload";
 Emailobj                        =  MessageGetRequestObj.Execute();
```

What can be the issue for it? Is Gmail api supports the encrypted emails ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: When you try to "store the email locally", what object is the "target" expecting?

Comment: We are storing it as EML

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the format parameter here [1], you can only retrieve the full email message data in the payload field (if you use “full” format) or in the raw field (if you use “raw” format).

If you use the raw format, you can get the full email message data with body content as a base64url encoded string  like this: `Emailobj.Raw` [2].

If you use the full format, you can get the object with the full email message data including body like this -> `Emailobj.Payload`, to obtain the headers list -> `Emailobj.Payload.Headers`, to obtain the body object -> `Emailobj.Payload.Body`. Check the payload part [2] and how to access its attributes [3] .

You also can use the “Try this API” feature here [1], to check the structure of the Message object [2] you receive when you run the request.

About the error you get when you try to “store the email locally”,  depending on what you mean by this, i have 2 answers:

If you mean to simply store the Message object [2] in your Emailobj variable:

1) Your Emailobj is an Email class reference (which appear to be a personal class from you), so you can’t store a Message object class from Google Library in that variable, because this class doesn’t have your personal class as a parent class. As stated in the documentation, the Message class only inherit from the IDirectResponseSchema interface [2]. Further information about inheritance here [4].

2) If you are trying to send the email to a server/application:

You should check how the target destination where you want to store the email is expecting the full email data, either an encoded string with all the data, a Json formatted object with a specific structure of headers and body, a Blob, etc.

**EDIT**

As you need to send it as an EML, you should find a way to create a blob object with “message/rfc2822” as the content-type (mimeType) and the raw string as the data, which you obtained from the raw format option `Emailobj.Raw`. Maybe this help [5].

[1] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

[2] https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Message.html

[3] https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1MessagePart.html

[4] https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1445/Introduction-to-inheritance-polymorphism-in-C

[5] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=linux